# Como o Git identifica a alteração de um arquivo?

Tags: git

#### Cenário exemplo

Tenho a pasta `projetos` no servidor.

Em minha máquina local, onde tenho o Git, criei uma pasta `empresa`, onde copiei todos os arquivos da pasta `projetos` do servidor.

Fiz o `add`, `commit` e `push` de tudo, para o *GitLab*.

#### Dúvidas

- Se eu alterar um arquivo no servidor, copiar esse arquivo, e jogar na pasta `empresa` da minha máquina, **o Git vai identificar que foi modificado**?

  - Pela **data de modificação ou pelo conteúdo** do arquivo?
- Dessa forma: copiando do servidor e colando na máquina local para fazer o `push`, não teria problema algum, correto!?

*(sim, entendo que o mais correto seria ter o Git no servidor, mas a pergunta é nesse cenário específico, para quem não tem como ter o Git no servidor)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você copiar um arquivo de algum lugar ou editar o arquivo no seu repositório dá na mesma, alteração é alteração não importa como ela foi feita.

Geralmente o Git pega metadados do arquivo para identificar, então o *timestamp* da modificação é usado. Em alguns casos ele pode fazer algo mais complexo até para [evitar condições de corrida](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/%7Eblynn/gg/race.html). E até onde eu sei é detalhe de implementação. É curioso saber, porém não deve confiar nesta informação para alguma atividade que dependa disso.

Então se copiar com horário mais antigo ele pode não conseguir identificar que foi alterado, depende da forma que vai copiar para saber se o horário será alterado ou não no momento da cópia.

O Git funciona se tudo estiver dentro da normalidade, se fizer brincadeiras ou uso anormal do sistema de arquivo ele pode entrar em parafuso :)